# How to update clojure version on ubuntu 12?

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, ubuntu-12.04, leiningen

I've installed clojure using 'apt-get install' command and than using the same command I've installed the leiningen. But when I'm typing in console 'clojure' it wtires me that I have 1.1.0 version. But I want to have at least 1.5.* version of clojure. 
I know that maybe I should not install leiningen in this way...
What could I do to upgrage the clojure to 1.5.* version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) is the defacto in Clojure world. You will make a lot of friends if leiningen is envolved in your question, not to mention it is rich in features and really awesome. Leiningen is optimized for Clojure and ClojureScript development.

Don't install Clojure that way, even Homebrew has deleted Clojure as formula.

You are using Ubuntu 12 and still you get Clojure 1.1.0 Imagine how Clojure version is very outdated at Ubuntu repos.

Comment: To elaborate, it is also better to install leiningen as a local user, so that you can run `lein upgrade` to pull yourself up to the latest version without sudo.

Comment: To elaborate, all Leiningen needs to run is Java. Once Leiningen is installed, you only have to specify which Clojure version you want each of your projects to depend on in the ``project.clj`` file. It'll automatically be downloaded the first time you try to do something with your project.

Comment: Max Noel, thanks. But I need that clojure 1.5.* was installed to LightTable IDE.

Comment: afaik lighttable will fetch clojure automatically. I think you'll need only jdk. Here is ppa for installing sun jdk - https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

Comment: The answer doesn't resolve original question - how do you get newer clojure.